# JavaScript runtime error: Expected ':' in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

running out of ideas, see if someone can help me.

This is part of my code, edit function for dropdown on Kendo grid. Works perfectly fine on FireFox and Chrome, only IE(I have 11 version) is giving me that weird error on edit click. This code get populated when user is clicking on Edit button.

```
$('#sleevegrid').data('kendoGrid').columns[5].editor = "<input id='SleeveSubProductID' name='SleeveSubProductID' style='width: 135px' type='text'/>\
            <script>jQuery(function(){jQuery('#SleeveSubProductID').kendoDropDownList(\
            {\
                'valuePrimitive': true,\
                'dataSource':\
                    {\
                        'transport':\
                            {'read':{\
                                        'url':'/NewAccounts/SubProducts_Read',\
                                        'data': getProduct,\
                                                function() \
                                                    {\
                                                        return kendo.ui.DropDownList.requestData(jQuery('#SleeveSubProductID'));\
                                                        }\
                                        },\
                            'prefix':''},\
                            'serverFiltering':true,\
                            'change':SleeveSubProductID_OnEdit_DataSourceChange,\
                            'filter':[],\
                            'schema':{'errors':'Errors'}\
                        },\
                'dataTextField':'SubProductName',\
                'autoBind':true,\
                'dataValueField':'SubProductID',\
                'optionLabel':'Please Select One'});\
                });<" + "/script>";
```

Error comes from jquery-1.9.1.js

`enter code here`globalEval: function( data ) {
        if ( data && jQuery.trim( data ) ) {
            ( window.execScript || function( data ) {
                **window[ "eval" ].call( window, data );**
            } )( data );
        }

Comment: You clearly have syntax errors, if you format that mess into something readable, it's quite clear -> **https://jsfiddle.net/qkhu7481/2/**

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.  The problem was in this line:

`{'read'{'url':'/NewAccounts/SubProducts_Read','data':getProduct},'prefix':''},\`